# Prove that there is no increasing function $f: \aleph_1 \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: set-theory

Someone gave a hint for this problem.

Hint: if such a function existed, there would be a rational between $f(\xi)$ and $f(\xi + 1)$ for each $\xi < \aleph_1$.

But I don't know how to apply this hint to the problem.
Maybe I think I should use the fact that the set of rational numbers is countable, but how?

Answer (score 1):

Assume such an $f$ exists.  For each ordinal $\xi \lt \aleph_1$, choose $g(\xi)$ to be a rational number such that $f(\xi) \lt g(\xi) \lt f(\xi + 1)$.  Then $g$ is $1$-$1$ (in fact, increasing) because $f$ is increasing, so $\{g(\xi) \mid \xi \lt \aleph_1 \}$ is an uncountable set of rational numbers, which is a contradiction, so no such $f$ can exist.